# Itens drag'n'drop dentro de tabela

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde pessoal, estou querendo criar uma tabela com eventos interativos, semelhante ao FullCalendar,
queria saber se alguém conhece alguma biblioteca que permita a criação de quadrados/retângulos que tenha drag'n'drop como os do [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) ou se é possivel configurar para que a categoria de eventos apareça no eixo y e as datas no eixo x.

Comment: **BOM DIA**.Seja bem vindo ao site, aconselho ver este link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour para utilizar o site adequadamente e satisfazer todas as suas dúvidas.

Comment: editei a pergunta pra melhor entendimento

Answer (score 0):

Para drag and drop você poderá usar o Sortable do jQuery UI [`vê a documentação`](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

```js
$("table tbody").sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).find('td').last().html(index + 1)
    });
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  background: #fff;
  border-width: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B8B8B8;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tr.even {
  td,
  th {
    background: #f1f1f1;
  }
}

thead,
tfoot {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  th {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}

body {
  color: #111;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="ui-state-default">
      <th colspan="4">Categoria</th>
      <th colspan="4">Data</th>
      <td colspan="4">Orden</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr class="ui-state-default">
    <th colspan="4">Festa Juninas</th>
    <td colspan="4">24 junho</td>
    <td colspan="4">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ui-state-default even">
    <th colspan="4">Natal</th>
    <td colspan="4">25 dezembro</td>
    <td colspan="4">2</td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Só não ficou muito claro para mim essa questão

> "se é possivel configurar para que a categoria de eventos apareça no
>   eixo y e as datas no eixo x."

Comment: Essa parte seria caso fosse usar o FullCalendar mesmo, ai queria que ficasse algo parecido com isso: https://i.imgur.com/IQDLrsT.png

;
No caso de utilizar o sortable do jQuery não daria certo por queria transformar a foto de cima em algo assim: https://i.imgur.com/y5bIMF7.png pra poder arrastar apenas os quadrados de um dia pro outro ou de um quarto pro outro.